# Focus iFrame in mat-dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe, angular-material, google-slides

I am using mat-dialog to display one of the slideshow created in google-slides. After opening a dialog I want user to navigate through slides using arrow keys. But this only works when user manually clicks on the slides for first time. 
The issue here is, I am unable to bring a focus inside iFrame. Below is a code snippet to simulate my use-case.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-9ttgpd

I tried using 
`this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow.focus()` but no success. Is there any other technique of bringing a focus inside presentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try waiting for iframe to be loaded

```
<iframe ... (load)="$event.target.contentWindow.focus()">
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-9whs4v?file=app%2Falert-dialog%2Falert-dialog.component.ts)**

Comment: This is really helpful. Thank you so much for this answer. But I would like to know why my approach of ngAfterViewInit hood did not work in this case? I think that hook should get called after initializing iframe, right?

Comment: ngAfterViewInit hooks gets called after template initialization, meaning after all html nodes are created. But it doesn't mean that it wait for iframe to be load. It's loaded in the background, the same true for img tag